# Decrementing inside of an if statement C++

Tags: c++

I am confused as to how to have equivalent logic without having the the decrement inside of the if statement.

```cpp
if(A && !B && !(C--))
{
}
```

I thought that this is equivalent to:

```cpp
if(A && !B && !(C))
{
    C--;
}
```

Comment: `0` evaluates to `false` any other value evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Note that the `&&` operators use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so that the variable `C` is only decremented if the third sub-expression is evaluated, which only happens if the first two sub-expressions are true. It is not necessary for the third sub-expression to also be true for the decrement to take place.

Comment: Please do not substantially change the question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. Since your most recent edit invalidated at least one answer, I have reverted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, `C` is decremented if the first two conditions are true.

In the second example, `C` is decremented if all three conditions are true.

The difference is that if `!C` is not true (the third condition is false), the first example will decrement C while the second will not.

Comment: So is the first the same as: 
```
if (A && !B)
{
   C--
}
```

Comment: @vvillp0wer5: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As a few before me have pointed out, the operator `&&` uses short-circuit evaluation. That means `!B` will be evaluated only if `A` is fulfilled and `!(C--)` will be evaluated only if `A && !B` is fulfilled.

(Well, unless there are some user defined `&&` operators in the mix but better to not think about that.)

The equivalent code would be:

```cpp
if(A && !B && !(C))
{
    C--;
}
else if(A && !B)
{
    C--;
}
```

or

```cpp
if(A && !B)
{
    if (!(C))
    {
        // Assuming you don't use "C" here.
    }
    C--;
}
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, the assumption "you don't use "C" here" is not necessarily valid.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix-decrement operator will decrement C when it executes, and return the old (pre-decrement) value.  So your first code snippet is more equivalent to:

```
int postdecrement(int & c)
{
   int ret = c;
   c = c-1;
   return ret;
}

if(A && !B && !(postdecrement(C)))
{
    // empty
}
```

Note that your second code snippet was different from your first one in that your second snippet,  C would only be decremented in the case where C was already 0.